# Multiple Harshad Number

Tags: java

```
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int c, d, sum = 0,sum1=0,n1=0,count=0;
        while(n>1)
        {
               c=n;
               while(c>0)
               {
               d = c%10;
               sum = sum + d;
               c = c/10;
               }
               if(n%sum==0)
               {
               sum1=sum;
               n1=n;
               n=n/sum;

               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("Not an harshad");
                   break;
               }

        }
            if(n1%sum1==0)
            System.out.println("Number is multiple harshad");
            else
            System.out.println("Number is not multiple harshad");    
    }
}
```

This code is not working properly for multiple harshad number. it also giving same output for a number is not multiple harshad.when i enter 108 it gives multiple harshad but when i enter 8 it also give multiple harshad number. although 8 is not multiple harshad number

Sample input: 6804
Ans:
  6+8+0+4=18=>6804/18=378
  378=> 3+7+8=18=>378/18=21
  21=> 2+1=3
  =>21/3=7

Input: 126
Output : 126 is not harshad number

Comment: wap in java to enter a number and check number is multiple harshad or not. a multiple harshad is said to be when divided by the sum of its digits, produces another Harshad Number.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the input, the expected output, and the actual output in the question itself, not in the title (which should only be a short summary of your problem). Any crucial or important or relevant piece of information should be in the body of the question itself.

Comment: A number is called Harshad if it is divisible by the sum of its digits.
For example 102 is divisible by 3. 
This quotient is not Harshad because 34 is not divisible by 7.
108 is a Multiple Harshad Number because the process ends at 1:
108/9=12; 12/3=4; 4/4=1.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reset `sum` back to `0` in each iteration of your outer loop. As a result only the first iteration calculates the correct sum of digits.

```
    while(n>1) {
           sum = 0; // add this
           c=n;
           while(c>0)
           {
           d = c%10;
           sum = sum + d;
           c = c/10;
           }
           if(n%sum==0)
           {
           sum1=sum;
           n1=n;
           n=n/sum;

           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("Not an harshad");
               break;
           }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use loop counter.
- Check loop counter at last( to resolve your single digit multiple harshad number problem).
- Also check your sum of all digit must not equals 0 (zero) to avoid infinite loop problem.

Try below code

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int dividend=num;
    int divisor=0;
    int digit;
    int count=0;

    while(dividend>1){
        divisor=0;
        int temp=dividend;
        while(temp>0){
           digit = temp%10;
           divisor = divisor + digit;
           temp = temp/10;
        }
        if(dividend%divisor==0 && divisor!=1){
            dividend = dividend/divisor;
            count++;
        }else{
               break;
        }
    }
    if(dividend==1 && count>1){
        System.out.println("Number is Multiple Harshad");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Number is not Multiple Harshad");
    }
```

Comment: thanks shubham its working. but what was fault or error in my code?

Comment: One error is you have define and intialize the counter variable but newer use it.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.*;
class multiple_harshad_NUMBER {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0, s1 = 0, d = 0, s = 0, temp = 0;
    int  n = 6804;/*lets take it as its a multiple harshad number but if you are making a program to check whether a number is multiple harshad number or not then use Scanner class.(input)*/ 
    while (n != 0) {
      temp = n;/* assigning value to temp variable as n will be 0 at the end of inner loop*/
      while (n != 0) {//loop for digit by processing
        d = n % 10;
        s = s + d;
        n = n / 10;
      }// inner looop close
      s1 = temp / s;//s1 gets the quotient 
      if (temp % s == 0 && s != 1){//condition to check if the temp(variable) is at least harshad number
        n = s1;
        s = 0;
      }
    }// outer loop close
    if (s1 == 1) {
/*since a number is a multiple harshad number if and only if the end of the snippet is 1*/
  System.out.println("Is Multiple Harshad Number");
    } 
  else {
  System.out.println("Isn't Multiple Harshad Number");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: an explanation and correct indentation would be helpfull.

Comment: tell me if its any helpful now